# choosing the youtube video quality by using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation

I'm having an issue to select the video quality resolution from the youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhdoY-ckzx4.

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import threading


# This example will help us to open a video on youtube and skip the ads

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

class ChromeTime(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
        chrome_options.add_argument("disable-popup-blocking")
        #chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/hvaandres/Desktop/Dev_Projects/QA_Testing/Project_Video/chromedriver", options=chrome_options) #/usr/local/bin/chromedriver - Linux Machine
        self.driver.maximize_window()  

    def testing3(self):
        driver_chrome = self.driver

        driver_chrome.get("https://youtube.com")
        print("Opening Youtube")
        driver_chrome.find_element_by_name("search_query").send_keys("peter mckinnon")
        print("Looking for the youtuber")
        driver_chrome.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy").click()
        print("Finally, we found your youtuber!")
        time.sleep(5)
        driver_chrome.find_element_by_class_name("style-scope ytd-vertical-list-renderer").click()
        print("Trying to open thee video that you would like to watch")
        time.sleep(10)
        driver_chrome.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-ad-skip-button-container").click()
        print("You're skipping the ads")
        time.sleep(10)
        driver_chrome.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-popup ytp-settings-menu").click()
        time.sleep(10)

        print("Initial Page Title is : %s" %driver_chrome.title)
        windows_before  = driver_chrome.current_window_handle
        print("First Window Handle is : %s" %windows_before)


# Anything declared in tearDown will be executed for all test cases
    def tearDown(self):
        # Close the browser. 
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I need to know what is the right CSS selector or element that I need to hit to choose the right element.

I tried several elements, but it seems that I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

**I used this to target the button and open the settings menu.**

```
list = driver_chrome.find_elements_by_class_name("ytp-settings-button")
list[0].click()
```

I had to use the list because for some reason the class can sometimes appear twice. Using list[0] made it work consistently.

**Here is the result:**
[image]

**Here is the full working code:**

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import threading


# This example will help us to open a video on youtube and skip the ads

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

class ChromeTime(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
        chrome_options.add_argument("disable-popup-blocking")
        #chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) #/usr/local/bin/chromedriver - Linux Machine
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def testing3(self):
        driver_chrome = self.driver

        driver_chrome.get("https://youtube.com")
        print("Opening Youtube")
        driver_chrome.find_element_by_name("search_query").send_keys("peter mckinnon")
        print("Looking for the youtuber")
        driver_chrome.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy").click()
        print("Finally, we found your youtuber!")
        time.sleep(5)
        driver_chrome.find_element_by_class_name("style-scope ytd-vertical-list-renderer").click()
        print("Trying to open thee video that you would like to watch")
        time.sleep(10)
        driver_chrome.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-ad-skip-button-container").click()
        print("You're skipping the ads")
        time.sleep(10)
        list = driver_chrome.find_elements_by_class_name("ytp-settings-button")
        list[0].click()
        time.sleep(10)

        print("Initial Page Title is : %s" %driver_chrome.title)
        windows_before  = driver_chrome.current_window_handle
        print("First Window Handle is : %s" %windows_before)


# Anything declared in tearDown will be executed for all test cases
    def tearDown(self):
        # Close the browser.
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: any idea to select this on twitch? too many divs

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.ytp-button.ytp-settings-button').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Quality')]").click()

time.sleep(2)   # you can adjust this time
quality = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(string(),'144p')]")
print("Element is visible? " + str(quality.is_displayed()))

quality.click()
```