# youtube quality and playback speed using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

can someone help me to change playback speed (like 1.25,1.5,1.75 and 2)  in you tube using python selenium.
And also for quality change (144,240,360..etc) test cases.
below link helped to write code for youtube.

Thanks in advance.

[choosing the youtube video quality by using selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538470/choosing-the-youtube-video-quality-by-using-selenium-in-python)

Comment: exactly what's your error ? Have you written anythhing?

Comment: yes i have tried below code, that is not selecting the quality.
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[28]/div[2]/div[2]/button[8]').click()
time.sleep(10)
list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ytp-settings-button")
list[0].click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for to play youtbue video in different resolutions.

settings -->  Quality --> select resolution

```
def test_240p_resoultion(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("")
    self.driver.get(self.url)
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)
    print("To click on settings button")
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-settings-button").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    data = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-menuitem:nth-child(4) > .ytp-menuitem-label").text
    print(data)
    print("To click on quality button")
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-menuitem:nth-child(4) > .ytp-menuitem-label").click()
    time.sleep(3)

    resoultion = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-menuitem:nth-child(5) > .ytp-menuitem-label").text
    print(resoultion)
    print("to click on 240p resolution")
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-menuitem:nth-child(5) > .ytp-menuitem-label").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for settings -->  Quality --> select resolution

```
def test_240p_resoultion(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("")
    self.driver.get(self.url)
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)
    

    print("To click on settings button")
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-settings-button").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    
    data = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-menuitem:nth-child(4) > .ytp-menuitem-label").text
    print(data)
     print("To click on quality button")
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-menuitem:nth-child(4) > .ytp-menuitem-label").click()
    time.sleep(3)

    resoultion = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-menuitem:nth-child(5) > .ytp-menuitem-label").text
    print(resoultion)
    print("to click on 240p resolution")
    self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-menuitem:nth-child(5) > .ytp-menuitem-label").click()
    time.sleep(3)

    self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the quality in URL like this:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx?vq=hd1080

Comment: Thanks for your support. that is not supporting now. i have implemented the code. please see my above comments.

Comment: edit your question instead of answering yourself